# ¿Cómo hacer la suma de los números enteros que hay entre dos números?

Tags: python, python-3.x

como estan?

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cual pensé que no sería tan dificil, pero a la hora de escribir el código, no puedo llegar a resolverlo.

Asi que recurro a la ayuda de utds, para ver si me lo pueden solucionar.

**El ejercicio dice lo siguiente:**

- Escribe un programa que solicite dos números enteros al usuario y muestre por pantalla la suma de
  todos los números enteros que hay entre los dos números (ambos números incluidos).

Calculo que esto se resuelve con un for, pero la verdad estuve un rato largo picando código y la verdad no puedo llegar a solucionarlo.

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias! :D

**EDIT**

En el PDF de los ejercicios muestra un ejemplo de como debe ser el resultado.

**Ejemplo :**

```
Introduce un número de inicio: 4
Introduce un número de fin: 8
El resultado es: 30
```

Y esto es uno de los códigos que hice para probar (**ESTA MAL, NO CUMPLE EL REQUISITO**):

```py
num1 = int(input("Introduce el primer número: "))
num2 = int(input("Introduce el segundo número: "))

for i in range(num1, num2):
    num1 += i
    print(num1)
```

Yo estoy usando como número de inicio 2; y número final un 6 (para poder hacer la suma de 2 hasta 5), pero la verdad no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: Saludos. Pon lo que has probado, los números con que estas probando, el resultado que obtienes y lo que debes obtener (es decir que te devuelves y que esperas). Desde luego con el proceso que se espera realices (ya que mencionas es un ejercicio).

Comment: Hola. Ya lo edité, espero se pueda entender mejor ahora, muchas gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Dos pistas: 1) Usa una variable adicional para acumular el total (iniciada en 0), 2) la función `range` no es inclusivo en su límite superior, esto quiere decir que tienes que sumarle uno al segundo número.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Tomando en cuenta que el primer número es menor...*

```
n = int(input("Ingrese el primer numero: "))
n2 = int(input("Ingrese elo segundo numero: "))
suma = 0;
for i in range (n, n2+1):
    suma = suma + i
print("La suam es: ", suma)
```

Comment: Me sirvió!! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! :D 
Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes visitar nuestra Organización en GitHub para más ayuda (https://github.com/Sansepi0l-s)